# Is it possible to handle several forms by one submit button?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, formik

I have a project on ReactJS which you can find [here](https://github.com/lpvmak/med_sched) (see develop-branch) or check it out on [our web site](http://medsched.online).
As you can see, I use [formik](https://jaredpalmer.com/formik/docs/overview) to handle forms.
Now I have only one submit button which handles all forms however it does not link with forms by `form` attribute. It was OK.

Unfortunately, I've faced a problem when having a go to implement form validation. I still prefer using [formik validation](https://jaredpalmer.com/formik/docs/guides/validation), but the thing is that it demands a direct connection between form and submit button like this:

```
export function GenerateButton(props) {
    return (
        <Button id="genButton"
                form="form1"
                type="submit"
                onClick={props.onClick}>
            Generate
        </Button>
    );
}
```

Any ideas how I can link all forms with submit button? 
Or I have to just use fictitious buttons in every form (position: absolute; left: -9999px;) and imitate their click after pushing generate button?

P.S. now there is `id="forms"` in html form tag, it is just stupid mistake, must be class attribute. I can generate unique id this way: `id={"form"+(props.index + 1)}`.

P.S.S. I am so sorry for my English.

Comment: Pass the form ID as a prop. That is what props are for. This button is just a generic component.

Comment: I pass form ID as a prop in React.useEffect. I do not understand how this is related to my question.

Comment: So you want to submit all forms at the same time with a single button?

Comment: @JMadelaine exactly.

Comment: ... if one talks about DOM, there is still the `document.forms` collection, This collection can be iterated over. Any form element features a `submit` method.

Answer (score 1):

The fieldArray solution looks quite complex and I think useFormik is a better option here.

For example:

```js
import React from 'react'

import { Button, Grid, TextField } from '@mui/material'
import clsx from 'clsx'
import { useFormik } from 'formik'

export function MyFormComponent(props: any) {
  const formA = useFormik({
    initialValues: {
      age: 23
    },
    onSubmit: values => {
      alert(JSON.stringify(values, null, 2))
    }
  })

  const formB = useFormik({
    initialValues: {
      name: 'bar'
    },
    onSubmit: values => {
      alert(JSON.stringify(values, null, 2))
    }
  })

  const formC = useFormik({
    initialValues: {
      description: 'A flat object'
    },
    onSubmit: values => {
      alert(JSON.stringify(values, null, 2))
    }
  })

  const submitForm = () => {
    //get your values here
    const values1 = formA.values
    const values2 = formB.values
    const values3 = formC.values

    //data access for storing the values
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <form onSubmit={formA.handleSubmit}>
        <TextField
          style={{ marginBottom: 20 }}
          fullWidth
          type='number'
          label='Age'
          id='age'
          name='age'
          InputProps={{
            inputProps: {
              min: 0
            }
          }}
          onChange={formA.handleChange}
          value={formA.values.age}
        />
      </form>

      <form onSubmit={formB.handleSubmit}>
        <Grid container spacing={2}>
          <Grid item xs={6}>
            <TextField
              onChange={formB.handleChange}
              value={formB.values.name}
              style={{ marginRight: 20 }}
              fullWidth
              name='name'
              type='text'
              label='Name'
              InputProps={{
                inputProps: {
                  min: 0
                }
              }}
            />
          </Grid>
        </Grid>
      </form>

      <form onSubmit={formC.handleSubmit}>
        <Grid container spacing={2}>
          <Grid item xs={6}>
            <TextField
              onChange={formC.handleChange}
              value={formC.values.description}
              style={{ marginRight: 20 }}
              fullWidth
              name='description'
              type='text'
              label='Description'
              InputProps={{
                inputProps: {
                  min: 0
                }
              }}
            />
          </Grid>
        </Grid>
      </form>

      <Button color='secondary' variant='contained' onClick={submitForm}>
        Submit
      </Button>
    </div>
  )
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can handle this with [fieldarray](https://jaredpalmer.com/formik/docs/api/fieldarray) of Formik very easily.
you will have an array and a list of forms in it then you can simply add and remove forms.
you won't have any problem with using validation of Formik too.
here is an example that exactly does what you want:

```
import React from "react";
import { Formik, Form, Field, FieldArray } from "formik";

const formInitialValues = { name: "", lastName: "" };
const FormList = () => (
  <Formik
    initialValues={{ forms: [formInitialValues] }}
    onSubmit={values =>
      setTimeout(() => {
        alert(JSON.stringify(values, null, 2));
      }, 500)
    }
    render={({ values }) => (
      <Form>
        <FieldArray
          name="forms"
          render={arrayHelpers => (
            <div>
              {values.forms.map((formItem, index) => (
                <div key={index}>
                  <Field name={`forms.${index}.name`} />
                  <Field name={`forms.${index}.lastName`} />
                  <button
                    type="button"
                    onClick={() => arrayHelpers.remove(index)} // remove a form from the list of forms
                  >
                    -
                  </button>
                  <button
                    type="button"
                    onClick={() =>
                      arrayHelpers.insert(index, formInitialValues)
                    } // insert an empty string at a position
                  >
                    +
                  </button>
                </div>
              ))}
              <div>
                <button type="submit">Submit</button>
              </div>
            </div>
          )}
        />
      </Form>
    )}
  />
);

export default FormList;
```

I have provided a [code sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/formik-field-array-p9v5e) version for you too
please let me know if you still have any problem

more reading:
https://jaredpalmer.com/formik/docs/api/fieldarray#fieldarray-array-of-objects

Comment: Thank you so much for this idea. I take it to notice and probably will refactor my code. In all honesty, it scares me a little bit, because now I have completely another approach. But I gonna try tomorrow.

Answer (score 0):

I'm created a special utility library to work with multiple forms (including repeatable forms) from one place. I see that you are using `Formik` component (instead of `useFormik` hook), but maybe it still be useful.

Check this example
https://stackblitz.com/edit/multi-formik-hook-basic-example?file=App.tsx

You can find the library [here](https://github.com/grigorii-zander/multi-formik-hook)